# Trouble converting for loop into recursive function in python

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I am trying to write a program that finds the max sum of nonadjacent elements in a 1 dimensional array and so far I have this:

```
def find_max_sum(arr):
    incl = 0
    excl = 0

    for i in arr:

        # Current max excluding i 
        new_excl = excl if excl>incl else incl

        # Current max including i
        incl = excl + i
        excl = new_excl

    # return max of incl and excl
    return (excl if excl>incl else incl)
```

It works.  My only question is how would one go about transforming this function into a recursive function without using the for loops?  My brain can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: Can you attempt to rephrase the problem you're working on?

Regardless of the specifics, likely what you'll want to do is have `find_max_sum(arr)` call `find_max_sum(arr[1:])` or `find_max_sum(arr[:-2])` (so, shrink the size of the array by some amount in each step, likely one), with a base case of an array of size 1.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**: rewrite your function so it is more Pythonic

```
def find_max_sum(lst):
    incl, excl = 0, 0

    for i in lst:
        incl, excl = excl + i, max(excl, incl)

    return max(excl, incl)
```

**Step 2**: now it is easy to rewrite it to a recursive function

```
def find_max_sum_recursive(lst, incl, excl):        
    if len(lst) > 0:
        i = lst[0]
        incl, excl = excl + i, max(excl, incl)

        return find_max_sum_recursive(lst[1:], incl, excl)
    else:
        return incl, excl

def call_find_max_sum_recursive(lst):
    return max(find_max_sum_recursive(lst, 0, 0))
```

Now you call

```
>>> call_find_max_sum_recursive([1, 2, 10, 3, 4])
15
```

Step 1 is not absolutely necessary. After all it is about the block of code in your `for i in arr:` and how they affect `incl` and `excl`. However it might help you rewriting.

Comment: Using a tuple in the parameter list is not supported in Python3 (PEP 3113).

Comment: @VPfB Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: FWIW, here's a one-liner version of the Python 3 version: `def find_max_sum_recursive(lst, t): return find_max_sum_recursive(lst[1:], (lst[0] + t[1], max(*t))) if lst else t`. It's generally considered more Pythonic to do `if lst:` than `if len(lst) > 0:`; OTOH, your version has the advantage that it will complain in the `if` statement if `lst` isn't an indexable collection.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for your feedback. However I disagree about `if lst:` to be prefered over `if len(lst) > 0`.

Comment: Fair enough. But I did say that your version does have an advantage. :) Actually, my statement wasn't quite correct: I should've said that yours will complain in the `if` statement if `lst` doesn't have a length, since there are many objects that have a well-defined length but which aren't indexable (eg sets).